# Bold Futura with Pillow not possible?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, macos-monterey

I'm using Pillow 9.4.0 with Python 3.11 on macOS Monterey

I want to create text on images with the Futura font.
Font Book and Preview show that the font has a bold variant, but this code throws an OSError stating that the font is not a variation font :-(

```
title_font = ImageFont.truetype("Supplemental/Futura.ttc")
title_font.set_variation_by_name("bold")
```

Has someone any idea to fix this?

Complete stack trace

```
../helper/ThumbnailCreator.py:38: in add_text
    title_font.set_variation_by_name("bold")
../../venv311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py:834: in set_variation_by_name
    names = self.get_variation_names()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont object at 0x106c08dd0>

    def get_variation_names(self):
        """
        :returns: A list of the named styles in a variation font.
        :exception OSError: If the font is not a variation font.
        """
        try:
>           names = self.font.getvarnames()
E           OSError: invalid argument

../../venv311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py:823: OSError
```

```
python -m PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Pillow 9.4.0
Python 3.11.0rc1 (v3.11.0rc1:41cb07120b, Aug  5 2022, 11:44:46) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from /Users/jb/PycharmProjects/blog_content_creatronix/venv311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL
Binary modules loaded from /Users/jb/PycharmProjects/blog_content_creatronix/venv311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok, compiled for 9.4.0
--- TKINTER support ok, loaded 8.6
--- FREETYPE2 support ok, loaded 2.12.1
--- LITTLECMS2 support ok, loaded 2.14
--- WEBP support ok, loaded 1.3.0
--- WEBP Transparency support ok
--- WEBPMUX support ok
--- WEBP Animation support ok
--- JPEG support ok, compiled for libjpeg-turbo 2.1.4
--- OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support ok, loaded 2.5.0
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok, loaded 1.2.13
--- LIBTIFF support ok, loaded 4.5.0
*** RAQM (Bidirectional Text) support not installed
*** LIBIMAGEQUANT (Quantization method) support not installed
--- XCB (X protocol) support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BLP
Extensions: .blp
Features: open, save, encode
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BMP image/bmp
Extensions: .bmp
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BUFR
Extensions: .bufr
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CUR
Extensions: .cur
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DCX
Extensions: .dcx
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DDS
Extensions: .dds
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DIB image/bmp
Extensions: .dib
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
EPS application/postscript
Extensions: .eps, .ps
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FITS
Extensions: .fit, .fits
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FLI
Extensions: .flc, .fli
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FTEX
Extensions: .ftc, .ftu
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GBR
Extensions: .gbr
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GIF image/gif
Extensions: .gif
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GRIB
Extensions: .grib
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
HDF5
Extensions: .h5, .hdf
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ICNS image/icns
Extensions: .icns
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ICO image/x-icon
Extensions: .ico
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IM
Extensions: .im
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IMT
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IPTC
Extensions: .iim
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
JPEG image/jpeg
Extensions: .jfif, .jpe, .jpeg, .jpg
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
JPEG2000 image/jp2
Extensions: .j2c, .j2k, .jp2, .jpc, .jpf, .jpx
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MCIDAS
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MPEG video/mpeg
Extensions: .mpeg, .mpg
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MSP
Extensions: .msp
Features: open, save, decode
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PCD
Extensions: .pcd
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PCX image/x-pcx
Extensions: .pcx
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIXAR
Extensions: .pxr
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PNG image/png
Extensions: .apng, .png
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PPM image/x-portable-anymap
Extensions: .pbm, .pgm, .pnm, .ppm
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PSD image/vnd.adobe.photoshop
Extensions: .psd
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SGI image/sgi
Extensions: .bw, .rgb, .rgba, .sgi
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SPIDER
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SUN
Extensions: .ras
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TGA image/x-tga
Extensions: .icb, .tga, .vda, .vst
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TIFF image/tiff
Extensions: .tif, .tiff
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WEBP image/webp
Extensions: .webp
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WMF
Extensions: .emf, .wmf
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XBM image/xbm
Extensions: .xbm
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XPM image/xpm
Extensions: .xpm
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XVTHUMB
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does `title_font.get_variation_names()` return? If `bold` is there it might be written as `Bold`. `set_variation_by_name()` is case sensitive.

Comment: The OSError is thrown by get_variation_names(self):

Comment: You could make it easier for folks to help you by showing where you downloaded this font from along with a long listing of the filenames in your `Supplemental` directory.

Comment: It is the standard Futura font on macOS under /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental

Comment: Please click [edit] and paste in the output from running `python3 -m PIL` or `python -m PIL` if you use an unversioned invocation of Python.

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with fonts, but there seem to be *"static"* and *"variation"* fonts. The static ones seem to require a separate file for each weight, whereas the variation ones can contain multiple weights (and possibly other features) in a single file.

The PIL/Pillow source code says it generates the error you observe when a font is not a variation font. I have no idea how you can tell from **FontBook** if a font is of the static or variation variety, but I guess that *"Futura"* is static and that's why your call to `get_variations()` fails.

It seems to work fine if you select other fonts such as `SFNSMono.ttf`:

```
In [21]: title_font = ImageFont.truetype("SFNSMono.ttf")

In [22]: title_font.get_variation_names()
Out[22]: [b'Light', b'Regular', b'Medium', b'Semibold', b'Bold', b'Heavy']
```

or `NewYork.ttf`:

```
In [23]: title_font = ImageFont.truetype("/System/Library/Fonts/NewYork.ttf")

In [24]: title_font.get_variation_names()
Out[24]: 
[b'Regular',
 b'Regular G1',
 b'Regular G2',
 b'Regular G3',
 b'Regular G4',
 b'Medium',
 b'Semibold',
 b'Bold',
 b'Bold G1',
 b'Bold G2',
 b'Bold G3',
 b'Bold G4',
 b'Heavy',
 b'Black']
```